# Integration Testing ServiceStack on MonoDevelop(Xamarin)

Tags: mono, servicestack

Hi I'm new to Mono and ServiceStack, and I'm having trouble running integration tests on Xamarin Studios on OSx.

I'm following the examples here [AppHostListenerBaseTests.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/AppHostListenerBaseTests.cs), but I can't get the test to pass.

```
    private const string listeningOn = "http://localhost:8080/";
    private myAppHost appHost; // extends AppHostHttpListenerBase

    [TestFixtureSetUp()]
    public void TestFixtureSetUp ()
    {
        appHost = new myAppHost ();
        appHost.Init ();
        appHost.Start (listeningOn);

        System.Console.WriteLine("ExampleAppHost Created at {0}, listening on {1}",
                                 DateTime.Now, listeningOn);
    }

    [TestFixtureTearDown()]
    public void TestFixtureTearDown ()
    {
        if (appHost == null)
            return;
        appHost.Dispose ();
        appHost = null;
    }

    [Test()]
    public void StartupWebService ()
    {
       html = listeningOn.GetStringFromUrl();
       Assert.That(html.Contains("The following operations are supported."));
    }
```

Mono will always throw the **System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error(404).**

It is confusing because building the entire web-service works fine. It starts up and arrives at the metapage, but attempting to run it in a test with the same code just breaks. I'm not sure if this is a problem with Xamarin on OSx, or that I am just missing something simple in my test cases. Has anyone dealt with a similar problem before?

Answer (score 1):

On your case i assume you are not running the integration tests form an emulator, but from a real device.

If that is the case, its normal that you receive a 404 since http://localhost:8080/ probably only exists in your machine, not the phone.